# What is the recommended power and connection height for a "design" radiator in a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, radiator

I need to provide the builder of my new house the height from floor of the water connections for the radiator of my bathroom.

Right now I have a 1800 x 3100 mm bathroom with a "design radiator" (the tall ones where you can hang towels on multiple levels). The radiator is 500 x 1150 mm (taller than wider). The connections for the water are at the top, at 1920 mm height. Above the bathroom is the roof (plus an empty cold space for storage), below the bathroom is another bathroom.

My new bathroom will have a living room below and a heated attic above it, therefore less heat loss, but is 16% bigger: 1800 x 3600 mm.

In both cases the radiator must be located on the long wall next to the door.

Using the [values from a shop](https://www.gamma.nl/assortiment/verwarming-ventilatie/radiatoren/c/verwarming-en-ventilatie_radiatoren?q=fh_location%3D%2F%2Fcatalog01%2Fnl_NL%2Ffh_item_type%3E%7Bproduct%7D%2Fcategories%3C%7Bcatalog01_catverwarming2den2dventilatie%7D%2Fcategories%3C%7Bcatalog01_catverwarming2den2dventilatie_catverwarming2den2dventilatie_radiatoren%7D%2Ftype_radiator%3E%7Bdesignradiator%7D%2F1001.0%3Cnet_height%3C1500.0%2F501.0%3Cnet_width%3C1000.0%2Fkleurfamilie%3E%7Bwit%7D%26fh_refpath%3D712a45f3-89f7-4175-9941-295a4ea75ae4%26fh_reffacet%3Dkleurfamilie%26fh_refview%3Dlister), I estimate that my current radiator (500 x 1150 mm) should provide about 650 W at 75C water temperature (there are products with the same size and 550-750 W, plus [one 435W](https://www.gamma.nl/assortiment/haceka-designradiator-merzouga-geborsteld-rvs-435-watt-120x50-cm/p/B298833) quite similar to my current one). It is set usually to a bit less than half power, but I admit the actual water temperature in my building is unknown to me, but it's quite hot at the touch of the pipes. In the new house the water temperature will be lower, given the use of floor heating.

I guess I can use a similar radiator, but how can I estimate more accurately the power (and therefore the size) required for the new one in the new house?

After knowing the height of the radiator, I have to choose the position of the water connection. The height is more or less fixed to be easily accessible, but I can choose between water connections on top of the radiator, or on the bottom side. Which one is preferable?

Answer (score 0):

Is this radiator heated by hot water or by electricity. You are speaking in terms of wattage which indicates an electrical appliance. If it is heated by hot water from your central heating system then the temperature and heating capacity will vary depending on the type of system installed. Also will this radiator be providing the heat for the bathroom or be used just as a towel warmer. Is this a 2nd. bathroom, since paragraph 1 and 2 seem to indicate different rooms above and below. When you say "hot to the touch", 140 degree anything will be hot to the touch but will not provide much usable heating capacity. A better description of your need would be helpful.

Comment: It's with water, but the spec sheets do include the wattage at various water temperatures. 75C is the standard temperature http://www.hornbach.nl/shop/SCHULTE-Designradiator-Turbo-wit-1135-x-600-mm/3875665/artikel.html